# The 'Content-Type' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.\r\nParameter name

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, contenttype

I am making a Http get request to 3rd party api using SSJS.
each time i make a call is get below exception:

```
e: {"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a Util.HttpRequest call. 
See inner exception for details.
URL: https://api-pre.vged.es/salesforcequiter-1.0/authentication/getTokenLogin
Method: GET
ClientID: 10965200
JobID: 0
ListID: 0
BatchID: 0
SubscriberID: 0
","description":
"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: 
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a Util.HttpRequest call. 
See inner exception for details.
URL: https://api-pre.vged.es/salesforcequiter-1.0/authentication/getTokenLogin
Method: GET
ClientID: 10965200
JobID: 0
ListID: 0
BatchID: 0
SubscriberID: 0
Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR
- from Jint -->
--- inner exception 1---
System.ArgumentException: The 'Content-Type' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name - from System
"}
```

Code snippet i tried:

```
var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(URL2);
//req.clearHeader();
 req.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  req.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
  req.setHeader("Authorization",auth);
  req.method = "GET";
  var resp = req.send();
```

or

```
var headername = ["Accept","Content-Type","Authorization"];
var headerValue = ["application/json","application/json",auth];
var result = HTTP.Get(URL2,headername,headerValue);
```

Both snippets gave me same exception.

Can some tell me if something is wrong with the code or is there some other way to get he response

Comment: do you have authorization token in "auth" which you are using in req.setHeader("Authorization",auth)

Comment: Are you sure that you should have the Content-Type header? It's most commonly used with PUT and POST requests. While Accept header is used with GET requests. I would try to remove Content-Type and only go with Accept and Authorization.